# Is it possible to define ivars in Objective-C extension?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I wonder if it is possible to write something like this in the .m file:

```
@interface MyController () {//ERROR here
    Foo *privateFoo; 
}
@end
```

I did it but I get :
`Expected identifier or '{' before '{' token`, I think I heard/watch a video (WWDC2010) saying this is possible or will be possible and currently only some architectures support it... but I not really sure and I cannot remember the video name.

I hope I can get some advice here.

Ignacio.

Comment: If you were to use the latest builds of the llvm 2.0 compiler then, yes, you could define instance variables in class extensions.

Comment: Judging by the fact that you got a compiler error when you tried it, I'd say the answer is "no".  Although as bbum says, this will be changing in the future, although my guess is that it will be restricted to the 64 bit runtime.

Comment: The above mentioned old thread has been removed by Apple. I think a new source for this background information might be [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in the modern runtime (64-bit/iOS) with clang (“LLVM Compiler 1.5”) in Xcode 3.2.3 or 3.2.4, by adding `-Xclang -fobjc-nonfragile-abi2` to the Other C Flags build setting. (Note that this is actually one option, not two.)

Another effect of this flag is to cause properties to be synthesized by default.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to handle it this way. Categories define additional behaviour only, not state.

Comment: That isn't a category, it is a class extension.  The rules are quite different.

Comment: I'm aware they're slightly different semantically, as described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1 ... However, nowhere there does it say one can add instance variables to extensions. Please point me at some resource there which does describe that behaviour, and I'll go ahead and remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit it doesn't state it explicitly, and the thread is pretty old, this document has an example at page 75 in which an ivar is added within an extension.

[The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/objc.pdf)